# No keyboard popup under google sign in page IOS SwiftUI (5.0.2)

Tags: ios, swiftui, google-signin

I have some problem on integrating google sign in (5.0.2) under my application 
The code below can trigger the signIn page , but can't receive the callback . I wonder if I missed something .Here is my code , hope any genius can help

`
struct SocialLogin: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

```
func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SocialLogin>) -> UIViewController {
     GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate  = context.coordinator

    return UIViewController()

}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SocialLogin>) {

}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject,GIDSignInDelegate {

    var parent: SocialLogin
    init(_ parent: SocialLogin) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        print("inside callback")
        if error != nil {
            Utility.hideProgress()
            return
        }else{
            guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
            print("Sign success by Google , get google info")
            var tempUser = ProviderUser()
            tempUser.userName = user.profile.name
            tempUser.firstName = user.profile.givenName
            tempUser.lastName = user.profile.familyName
            tempUser.email = user.profile.email
            tempUser.imgUrl = user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 100)?.absoluteString
            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                           accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
            parent.firebaseLogin(credential, provider: "google",user:tempUser)
        }
    }
}



func attemptLoginGoogle() {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
}
```

`

```
  var googleButton : some View {
    Circle()
        .fill(SwiftUI.Color.init(red: 219/255, green: 68/255, blue: 55/255))
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .overlay(
            Image("icon-google")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
    ).shadow(radius: 5)
        .onTapGesture {
            SocialLogin().attemptLoginGoogle()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the same flow for the google sign-in.

You need to make call/initialize the **SocialLogin()** in somewhere in the main view.

Please take a look at below implementation that how I achieved it.

=====

In the main content view, I have passed **SocialLogin()** as a view for button

```
Button(action: SocialLogin().attemptLoginGoogle(), label: {
      SocialLogin()
})
```

=====

ON **SocialLogin()** to return some UI

```
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SocialLogin>) -> UIView {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = context.coordinator

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "YOUR IMAGE NAME")
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    return imageView
}
```

and then you will be able to receive a call back in **struct SocialLogin: UIViewControllerRepresentable {**

It works for me